# Sql Job Failing with Timeout Error

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server, sql-server-agent, query-timeout

Recently I have noticed that a job is failing on our Production 2014 SQL Server with this error text:

> Timeout error [258]. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 258)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LinkedTestServer01" returned message "Login timeout expired". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LinkedTestServer01" returned message "Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.

The job fails during random times of the day and night. Sometimes even overnight (2am or 3am)

- The connection timeout and remote query property in the linked server property is set to 0.
- The Remote login Timeout property on the server itself is set to 10.
- I have been monitoring the server using Activity Monitor and DMV queries and am not seeing any blocking or deadlocks.
- There are no errors in windows event log or SQL error log that shows any timeout errors.
- Index maintenance is running nightly and there are no index fragmentation in the corresponding databases.
- There are no spikes in CPU. CPU does not go above 20% even during the busiest times of the days.
- There are no memory issue. Memory stays at a steady 88%.

In this scenario, what are the other ways I can find the root cause of this timeout error?

If you have faced this situation before, what did you do to solve this issue?

Comment: Is this lined server located at another site, maybe over VPN? If so, do you monitor the network connection?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - the linked server is always available as the linked server is connecting to another highly used production server that has availability groups set up.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - haven't been measuring it with any tools. but have not received any complaints regarding it and also do not see any errors in event logs/sql logs